# How can I use preprocessor symbols with custom build configurations?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, c-preprocessor

I'd like to create a build configuration that enables release mode but with some logging. I had envisioned it working with preprocessor symbols. So for instance, if you say `#if DEBUG` then it'll only compile the code block if the build is in DEBUG. I created a custom build called "ReleaseWithLogging", but the preprocessor doesn't recognize it.

Is it possible to achieve what I am asking, and if so, how? Or better yet, instead of using symbols, using the ConditionalAttribute

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean with "created custom build XXX", but assuming you've changed "conditional compilation symbols" in project properties-> build, it is not clear why the changes are not picked up. You may need to clarify what you did/how you run build.

Answer (score 6):

Right click your project and select **Properties**.

On the left side select the **Build** tab option.

On the right enter your **ReleaseWithLogging** symbol into the *Conditional compilation* *symbols* field.

Actually, you only enter this symbol definition for the configurations that need it. So when you select Release as the config at the top you set the symbol. When you select Debug at the config then you can omit it.

Then in you code...

```
#if ReleaseWithLogging
```

...will pass for the configs where you defined the symbol. From your description I assume you would only define it for your new custom ReleaseWithLogging config.

Comment: I think `ReleaseWithLogging` is the name of the new configuration that he created, not the name of the preprocessor symbol.

Comment: Yes, but I think he needs at add ReleaseWithLogging as a new symbol for that new configuration in order to have a #if work for just that config. Maybe I didn't make that clear in the answer.